# IE8 not showing div content

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have some content that, for some reason, is not being shown in IE8 (but works fine in Firefox).

The source shows that the code is created, and the box for the content is present and correct, but everything inside it (in `<div class="inside">`) is not shown. The class `.inside` is visible, as shown by the box above it being populated.

I've recorded a short video so that the problem can be seen. I'm totally lost for ideas, any suggestions appriciated. Thanks.

http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cl1YQFHO5

Comment: Please post your css and html code, and if possible provide a link to that page.

Comment: The page is part of our intranet, so I'm unable to post a link (hence the viedo). It's difficult to know what to post, as there are several files involved, but I'm trying to sort something out on Pastebin right now...

Comment: I don't know what the heck was happening, but it is now sorted. As far as I know, I did nothing, so I can only assume it was some bug with IE. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very localized, specific problem that the OP solved by himself. It was about just a corrupted file and nothing related to the topics mentioned in the question. It is not likely that anybody else can benefit from this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with my text editor (Total Edit) corrupting a file. Copying the contents in to a new file and overwriting the original solved the issue.